# How to script pairwise comparisons in a for loop in zsh using an if statement?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, zsh

I am running `zsh` (z shell) on a Mac.

I would like to run pairwise comparisons between all subjects in the list `subjects` without repeating overlapping comparisons, such as between subject1-subject2 *and* subject2-subject1. In this example, only the first comparison should be applied by the code.

```
subjects=(Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4)
for i in $subjects
do
for j in $subjects
do
if [ $i < $j ]
then
echo "Processing pair $i - $j ..."
fi
done
done
```

The output I get is:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: Subject1
zsh: no such file or directory: Subject2
zsh: no such file or directory: Subject3
zsh: no such file or directory: Subject4
zsh: no such file or directory: Subject1
...
```

What would be the correct operator in `if [ $i < $j ]` to exclude repeated comparisons? I also tried using `if [ "$i" '<' "$j" ]` but then I get `zsh: condition expected: <`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `<` argument to `[` to prevent it from being interpreted as an input redirection:

```
if [ $i \< $j ]
```

Or switch to `[[`, which bypasses regular command parsing.

```
if [[ $i < $j ]]
```

The command `[ $i < $j ]` is equivalent to `[ $i ] < $j`, with `[` being simply another name for the `test` command, not some kind of shell syntax.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. I now came across another small problem that I updated in my initial post.

Comment: If you have a new problem, start a new question; don't edit this one.

Comment: Sorry, will do.